# How can I see a JavaScript var into a function in my laravel code?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm working with Laravel to create a project for school, I have some code made in JavaScript to get the Digital Signature of a User, I need to call the var where the information is located in Laravel, in a function specifically.

This is the JavaScript code and the var `resultado` is the one that I need to call into Laravel.

```
/* Web-socket service */
async function service(jsonObject){
    var ws = new WebSocket(URL_SERVICE);

    // Es una función "anónima", que atiende la petición, 
    // si la función, dependiendo del caso, es exitosa le hace un resolve
    // si no le tira un reject. 
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var socket = ws;
        socket.onopen = function () {

            // No termina de operar hasta que el componente le envíe la respuesta. 
            socket.send(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
        };
        socket.onmessage = function (message) {

            // Devuelve la data de la información del componente. 
            // Este mensaje es el que tiene toda la data del Usuario. 
            resolve(message);
            console.log(message);

            // Así se puede atrapar la información de la persona. En esta variable 
            // se puede encontrar los detalles del nombre y los apellidos. 
            var resultado = message.data;
```

Comment: Add what you have tried till now as well

Comment: I did not understand the question, maybe it is just me, but maybe a little more editing / context would be good

Comment: Actually, I've tried nothing because I don't know how to

Comment: It's just, that I need to call the var of JavaScript into my code of PHP Laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data using Ajax Post Request to Laravel File

```
resolve(message);
console.log(message);

// Así se puede atrapar la información de la persona. En esta variable 
// se puede encontrar los detalles del nombre y los apellidos. 
var resultado = message.data;
data = 'data='+
```

Now, send that data to Laravel File.
If you use Post method than you can access data like

```
$data = $request->data;
```

Comment: ```data = 'data='+``` This line doesn't work on my code. :(